# How to use promises with IndexedDB without transactions auto-committing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise, async-await, indexeddb

Is there any way to use IndexedDB with promises and async/await without the transactions auto-committing? I understand that you can't do stuff like fetch network data in the middle of a transaction, but everything I was able to find online on the subject indicates that IndexedDB should still work if you simply wrap it in promises.

However, in my testing (Firefox 73), I found that simply wrapping the request's `onsuccess` method in a Promise is enough to cause the transaction to auto-commit before the promise executes, while the same code works when using the raw IndexedDB API. What can I do?

Here is a simplified minimal example of my code.

```
const {log, error, trace, assert} = console;

const VERSION = 1;
const OBJ_STORE_NAME = 'test';
const DATA_KEY = 'data';
const META_KEY = 'last-updated';

function open_db(name, version) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = indexedDB.open(name, version);
        req.onerror = reject;
        req.onupgradeneeded = e => {
            const db = e.target.result;
            for (const name of db.objectStoreNames) {db.deleteObjectStore(name);}
            db.createObjectStore(OBJ_STORE_NAME);
        };
        req.onsuccess = e => resolve(e.target.result);
    });
}
function idbreq(objs, method, ...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = objs[method](...args);
        req.onsuccess = e => resolve(req.result);
        req.onerror = e => reject(req.error);
    });
}
async function update_db(db) {
    const new_time = (new Date).toISOString();
    const new_data = 42; // simplified for sake of example

    const [old_data, last_time] = await (() => {
        const t = db.transaction([OBJ_STORE_NAME], 'readonly');
        t.onabort = e => error('trans1 abort', e);
        t.onerror = e => error('trans1 error', e);
        t.oncomplete = e => log('trans1 complete', e);
        const obj_store = t.objectStore(OBJ_STORE_NAME);
        return Promise.all([
            idbreq(obj_store, 'get', DATA_KEY),
            idbreq(obj_store, 'get', META_KEY),
        ]);
    })();
    log('fetched data from db');
    // do stuff with data before writing it back

    (async () => {
        log('beginning write callback');
        const t = db.transaction([OBJ_STORE_NAME], 'readwrite');
        t.onabort = e => error('trans2 abort', e);
        t.onerror = e => error('trans2 error', e);
        t.oncomplete = e => log('trans2 complete', e);
        const obj_store = t.objectStore(OBJ_STORE_NAME);
        // This line works when using onsuccess directly, but simply wrapping it in a Promise causes the
        // transaction to autocommit before the rest of the code executes, resulting in an error.
        obj_store.get(META_KEY).onsuccess = ({result: last_time2}) => {
            log('last_time', last_time, 'last_time2', last_time2, 'new_time', new_time);
            // Check if some other transaction updated db in the mean time so we don't overwrite newer data
            if (!last_time2 || last_time2 < new_time) {
                obj_store.put(new_time, META_KEY);
                obj_store.put(new_data, DATA_KEY);
            }
            log('finished write callback');
        };



        // This version of the above code using a Promise wrapper results in an error
        // idbreq(obj_store, 'get', META_KEY).then(last_time2 => {
        //     log('last_time', last_time, 'last_time2', last_time2, 'new_time', new_time);
        //     if (!last_time2 || last_time2 < new_time) {
        //         obj_store.put(new_time, META_KEY);
        //         obj_store.put(new_data, DATA_KEY);
        //     }
        //     log('finished write callback');
        // });



        // Ideally, I'd be able to use await like a civilized person, but the above example
        // shows that IndexedDB breaks when simply using promises, even without await.
        // const last_time2 = await idbreq(obj_store, 'get', META_KEY);
        // log('last_time', last_time, 'last_time2', last_time2, 'new_time', new_time);
        // if (!last_time2 || last_time2 < new_time) {
        //     obj_store.put(new_time, META_KEY);
        //     obj_store.put(new_data, DATA_KEY);
        // }
        // log('finished write callback');
    })();
    return [last_time, new_time];
}

open_db('test').then(update_db).then(([prev, new_]) => log(`updated db timestamp from ${prev} to ${new_}`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in a completely different part of my code.

At the end of my top level code, I had

```
.catch(e => {
    error('caught error', e);
    alert(e);
});
```

I'm not sure about the details, but showing an alert appears to cause all the transactions to autocommit, while the promises are still pending, leading the errors I saw once the user clicks "ok" on the alert popup and the pending promises continue. Removing the `alert` call from my global error handler fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Orchestrate promises around transactions, not individual requests.

If that causes problems with your design, and you still want to use indexedDB, then design around it. Reevaluate whether you need transactional safety or whether you need to actually reuse a transaction for several requests instead of creating several transactions with only a couple requests per transaction.

There is little to no overhead in spawning a large number of transactions with a small number of requests per transaction in comparison to spawning a small number of transactions with a large number of requests. The only real concern is consistency.

Any await is a yield in disguise. indexedDB transactions timeout when no requests are pending. A yield causes a gap in time so the transactions will timeout.

Comment: So that's a "no" then?

Comment: You can get away with wrapping requests in promises. The catch is that you can not await such promises because of how some browsers implement await. await can act like a yield, which allows for other operations to jump ahead of the awaited operation in the queue. During the time the enqueued task waits in the event loop, the transaction can timeout because indexedDB does not see any registered requests on the transaction.

Comment: If you want to get fancy and keep using promises, try this. only await the promise representing the completion of the transaction. *then* await the promises representing the requests. then you can use promises to your hearts desire.

Comment: The problem isn't await. Did you see my second example? IndexedDB autocommits even if you don't use await at all. Also, that suggestion is not helpful if you need to make a request that depends on the result of another request in the same transaction, like atomically reading a value and writing it back as in my example.

Comment: Good luck then!